# error Couldn't find package "babel-core" on the "npm" registry

Tags: yarnpkg, jfrog-cli

We are having a repository hosted on JFrog.

I deleted the

> node_modules
>   yarn.lock

but after running `yarn` command
I am getting the following error:`error Couldn't find package "babel-core" on the "npm" registry.`

In .npmrc file we've:

always-auth = true

node version:v8.11.3
yarn version: 1.17.2
global npm installs version:

```
├── appium@1.13.0
```

├── babel-core@6.26.3
├── create-react-app@3.0.1
├── npm@5.6.0
├── typescript@3.5.2
└── yarn@1.17.2

Kindly advise.